# Mule - Getting all the objects from AWS S3 bucket (more than 1000 files)

Tags: amazon-s3, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft

Need to retrieve all the objects from the S3 bucket. Currently have more than 1000+ objects.

Able to retrieve 1000 but need all of them at one i.e 1000+ objects.

```
<s3:list-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="test" prefix="test" maxKeys="15000" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>

<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.objectSummaries]">
<s3:get-object-content config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="#[payload.getBucketName()]" key="#[payload.getKey()]" doc:name="Amazon S3"/>

</foreach>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mule, but I can tell you that a `list-objects` call is limited to returning 1000 values. To obtain the next 1000 objects, you will need to pass the `starting-token` that was provided as `NextToken` in the result set. That tells it to continue from the next object. The `IsTruncated` field indicates whether there are more objects that can be listed.

Comment: By the way, if you need to retrieve information for a bucket with a large number of objects, you might consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html). It can provide a daily CSV file listing all objects.